# PHP download link restrictions

Tags: php, hyperlink, download, restriction

I'm trying to put some security on a download link/counter, but as a complete PHP newbie I'm not sure how to approach it.

Currently the download button links to a simple file.php that increases a simple download counter in a count.txt.

The file.php looks like this:

```
<?php

$hit_count = @file_get_contents('count.txt');
$hit_count++;
@file_put_contents('count.txt', $hit_count);

header('Location: examplename.zip'); // redirect to the real file to be downloaded
```

What would be the easiest way to add some protection here, on a per IP basis (or whatever is recommended)? I have no user variable, it's a public link without any registration required.

Ex:

- Restrict so that it can only be downloaded once and then you have to wait at least 30 minutes to click again
- Restrict to one download per day per IP
- Or some other good solution

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the users IP. As for restricting to one download per IP per day...you will have to do some work on that. You will need to store all IP addresses along with a time stamp and expire them after 6/12/24 hours. Some sort of SQL database will probably be best

Comment: Storing in db would be a lot more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is an IP base security.

Check this pseudo-code.

```
IF ip not stored
   store ip 
   store current_timestamp
   allow download
ELSE 
   Retreive stored timestamp for the ip
   IF currentstamp - retreived timestamp < 30min
      disallow
   ELSE
         update current_timestamp for ip
         allow download
```

You can store the IP in a file or in a database (mysql, postgresql, sqlite, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from a friend, and here is how he solved it with MD5/Hash + making the link valid for 5 minutes.

On the download page:

```
<? $time = time(); ?>
<a href="yourlink-path/file.php?time=<?=$time?>&hash=<?=md5($time.'BADASS')?>">DOWNLOAD HERE</a>
```

And in the file.php:

```
<?php

$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$linktime = $_GET['time'];

if (md5($linktime.'BADASS') == $hash) {

  // check if time is not older than 5 mins
  $currenttime = time();

  if (($currenttime - intval($linktime)) < 300) {

        // DOWNLOAD HERE
        $hit_count = @file_get_contents('count.txt');
        $hit_count++;
        @file_put_contents('count.txt', $hit_count);
        header('Location: myfile.zip'); // redirect to the real file to be downloaded

        exit;

    } else {

        // LINK IS TO OLD, do something here, maybe just:
        exit;

    }
} else {

    // Hash has been tampered with, do something, maybe just:
    exit;

}
```